# Setting a parameter value using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been attempting to use a stored procedure which calculates the total cost of a service to set the value of a "cost" parameter in a separate stored procedure.

The calculate stored procedure is working as intended (returns the correct value when I run it), and the second stored procedure is executing with no errors, however the value from the first stored procedure is not being carried over (returning 0 in my final table).

Here are the two stored procedures:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculateCost]
    ( @VIN INT,
      @BookingDate DATE, @BookingTime TIME(7),
      @ReturnDate DATE, @ReturnTime TIME(7)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) * Vehicle.HourlyRate) <= 0 
                 THEN 0 
                 ELSE (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) * Vehicle.HourlyRate) 
         END) + DATEDIFF(day, @BookingDate, @ReturnDate) * Vehicle.DailyRate AS Cost
    FROM 
        dbo.Vehicle
    WHERE 
        VIN = @VIN
END
```

Second stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateBooking]
    ( @BookingID INT, @CustomerID INT, @VIN INT,
      @BookingDate DATE, @BookingTime TIME(7),
      @ReturnDate DATE, @ReturnTime TIME(7),
      @OdoReadingInbound INT,
      @Discount FLOAT,
      @ObservationsIn NVARCHAR(50),
      @EmpID INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Cost money

    EXEC @Cost = dbo.calculateCost @BookingID, @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @ReturnDate, @ReturnTime

    UPDATE dbo.Booking
    SET CustomerID = @CustomerID,
        VIN = @VIN,
        BookingDate = @BookingDate,
        BookingTime = @BookingTime,
        ReturnDate = @ReturnDate,
        ReturnTime = @ReturnTime,
        OdoReadingInbound = @OdoReadingInbound,
        Discount = @Discount,
        ObservationsIn = @ObservationsIn,
        EmpID = @EmpID,
        Cost = @Cost
    WHERE BookingID = @BookingID
END
```

I'm by no means overly experienced with SQL so any help would be appreciated thanks, I've tried searching this problem myself for the past 30 minutes or so to no avail :)

**EDIT:** I'm now attempting to use an OUTPUT variable, however I'm still getting 0 as my final value from the second SP. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculateCost]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    ( @VIN int
    , @BookingDate date
    , @BookingTime time(7)
    , @ReturnDate date
    , @ReturnTime time(7)
    , @Cost money OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT (CASE WHEN 
            (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
            * Vehicle.HourlyRate) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
            (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
            * Vehicle.HourlyRate) END)
            + DATEDIFF(day, @BookingDate, @ReturnDate) 
            * Vehicle.DailyRate AS Cost
    FROM dbo.Vehicle
    WHERE VIN = @VIN
    RETURN
END
```

.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateBooking]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    ( @BookingID int
    , @CustomerID int
    , @VIN int
    , @BookingDate date
    , @BookingTime time(7)
    , @ReturnDate date
    , @ReturnTime time(7)
    , @OdoReadingInbound int
    , @Discount float
    , @ObservationsIn nvarchar(50)
    , @EmpID int
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @Cost money
    EXEC @Cost = dbo.calculateCost @BookingID, @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @ReturnDate, @ReturnTime, @Cost OUTPUT
    UPDATE dbo.Booking
    SET CustomerID = @CustomerID,
        VIN = @VIN,
        BookingDate = @BookingDate,
        BookingTime = @BookingTime,
        ReturnDate = @ReturnDate,
        ReturnTime = @ReturnTime,
        OdoReadingInbound = @OdoReadingInbound,
        Discount = @Discount,
        ObservationsIn = @ObservationsIn,
        EmpID = @EmpID,
        Cost = @Cost
    WHERE BookingID = @BookingID
END
```

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605242/how-to-set-the-result-of-exec-stored-procedure-to-a-variable

Comment: You need to use a return in the first stored procedure, so that it returns a scalar value, which can be assigned to a variable

Comment: you can use INSERT INTO table EXEC ...; OR RETURN; OR OUTPUT parameter

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the fast responses, I've just been reading up on a few of these methods.

Comment: I've edited my post, if anyone could help me out with this it would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: try printing the values of variables in second sp, after you've called them.

Comment: Hm... any reason why you didn't define a function with a result value as calculatecost??

Comment: @Tyron78 Besides ignorance, none whatsoever. I'll try that now thanks

Comment: @Tyron78 A function looks to be very similar to a SP, is this something can be used within my SP? Or is it meant to replace it.

Comment: use this : `EXEC dbo.calculateCost @BookingID, @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @ReturnDate, @ReturnTime, @Cost OUTPUT` in second sp. i dont think you need to specify "@cost =" . let me know if it works

Comment: @S.H it should replace your first SP and can be used in your second SP

Comment: @PrabhatG I've tried this and it unfortunately still returns nothing

Comment: @Tyron78 Is this a more practical solution? I was told that I should use a stored procedure for this and would like to get that to work, but I'm open to different ideas

Comment: @S.H could you provide some sample Data please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT @COST  = CASE WHEN 
        (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
        * Vehicle.HourlyRate) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
        (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
        * Vehicle.HourlyRate) END
        + DATEDIFF(day, @BookingDate, @ReturnDate) 
        * Vehicle.DailyRate AS Cost
FROM dbo.Vehicle
WHERE VIN = @VIN
RETURN
```

Can you try like this in calculateCost?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried this but get an error "The multi-part identifier "Vehicle.CoulmnName" could not be bound.".

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after fiddling around for a little I got my calculateCost SP to function properly outside of my updateBooking SP. I was encountering an error `"The multi-part identifier "Vehicle.CoulmnName" could not be bound."` which I resolved by removing `AS Cost` from the query. I using the following query to debug:

```
declare @Cost money
exec dbo.calculateCost 7
, '20170101'
, '18:00:00'
, '20170101'
, '20:30:00'
, @Cost output
print @Cost
```

Which printed the correct value. However the updateBooking SP was still not functioning correctly. After reading through it again I realised that I was passing `@BookingID` into calculateCost instead of `@VIN`, which was why it was not returning anything. Here the final code for both stored procedures in case it helps anyone in the future.

calculateCost:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculateCost]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    ( @VIN int
    , @BookingDate date
    , @BookingTime time(7)
    , @ReturnDate date
    , @ReturnTime time(7)
    , @Cost money OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @Cost = (CASE WHEN 
            (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
            * Vehicle.HourlyRate) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
            (DATEDIFF(hour, @BookingTime, @ReturnTime) 
            * Vehicle.HourlyRate) END)
            + DATEDIFF(day, @BookingDate, @ReturnDate) 
            * Vehicle.DailyRate
    FROM dbo.Vehicle
    WHERE VIN = @VIN
    RETURN
END
```

updateBooking:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateBooking]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    ( @BookingID int
    , @CustomerID int
    , @VIN int
    , @BookingDate date
    , @BookingTime time(7)
    , @ReturnDate date
    , @ReturnTime time(7)
    , @OdoReadingInbound int
    , @Discount float
    , @ObservationsIn nvarchar(50)
    , @EmpID int
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @Cost money
    EXEC dbo.calculateCost @VIN, @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @ReturnDate, @ReturnTime, @Cost OUTPUT
    UPDATE dbo.Booking
    SET CustomerID = @CustomerID,
        VIN = @VIN,
        BookingDate = @BookingDate,
        BookingTime = @BookingTime,
        ReturnDate = @ReturnDate,
        ReturnTime = @ReturnTime,
        OdoReadingInbound = @OdoReadingInbound,
        Discount = @Discount,
        ObservationsIn = @ObservationsIn,
        EmpID = @EmpID,
        Cost = @Cost
    WHERE BookingID = @BookingID
END
```

Comment: Looks OK :-) Just finished a similar solution. However, I prefer functions instead of SPs in most cases. :-D

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely look into it for future use. I was asked to make a stored procedure for this so I decided to stick to those requirements :).